# Generator comprehension running 200x slower under PyCharm debugger

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm

PyCharm Profession 2020.2

Python '3.8.0 (v3.8.0:fa919fdf25, Oct 14 2019, 10:23:27) \n[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)]'

Here is some sample code of summing a list via list comprehension vs via generator comprehension

```
def sum_with_generator():
    return sum(i * i for i in range(1, 1_000_000))

def sum_with_list():
    return sum([i * i for i in range(1, 1_000_000)])

def test():
    time1 = datetime.datetime.now()
    print(sum_with_generator())
    time2 = datetime.datetime.now()
    print(sum_with_list())
    time3 = datetime.datetime.now()
    print(f'Generator: {time2 - time1}; List: {time3 - time2}')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

If I run this code in PyCharm without the debugger, I get

```
Generator: 0:00:00.055020; List: 0:00:00.092192
```

Both less than a tenth of a second.  The generator is faster, I presume, because it doesn't build a list.
But If I run this same code under the debugger:

```
Generator: 0:00:12.039189; List: 0:00:00.363289
```

The generator code is now more than 200 times slower than it was before.  The list code is only about four times slower. In my actual code, this slowdown makes my code unrunnable.

Is this a known problem with PyCharm or Python?  Is there some switch to pass to make this slowdown less severe?

Comment: There seems to be some issues with regressions in performance in recent Pycharm versions. see: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-44270?_ga=2.5109619.1556034491.1601664091-1677767385.1591034629

Comment: Try to disable: Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Python Debugger -> Drop into debugger on failed tests flag.

Comment: @DeepSpace.  No difference

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga.  Not seeing any change.